# When created sub-directory, can we create a new navbar?

Tags: menus, multisite, directory, multi-language

I want to create a new sub directory for my wordpress website. But I will do this for second language option. I watched some videos and I saw that we can create new posts and pages but I didn't see creating a new navbar. Can we create new menu in subdirectory?

Comment: There's no subdirectories in WordPress. If you create a new subdirectory on the server, you'd need a separate WordPress install. Alternatively you could have a multisite, in which case each site gets its own menus anyway. Or, if you use a multi-language plugin, that would have its own way for managing different menus for different languages.

Comment: It's called sub-directories in wordpress, this is why I called like this. I mean same thing, multisite. I don't wanna use plugins, they will have updates. There will be just 2 language options. Thank u for answer.

Comment: ah you meant a multisite install